# Yii find or initialize method

Tags: activerecord, yii

I am looking for an equivalent Rails method in the Yii Framework on a class level that finds an existing record based on a passed in array that the ActiveRecord would need to match.  If found, this would return the matched ActiveRecord.  If it is not found, a newly instantiated ActiveRecord is returned.

Here is an example of how I am hoping it can look:

```
$person = Person::model()->find_or_initialize_by(array('name'=>'bob','age'=>20));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to the core CActiveRecord by extending it.  In protected/components/ActiveRecord.php, add:

```
class ActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
  public static function find_or_initialize_by($params)
  {
    if( ! $model = static::model()->findByAttributes($params) )
    {
      $model = new static();
      foreach($params as $name => $value)
        $model->$name = $value;
    }
    return $model;
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
$person = Person::find_or_initialize_by(array('name'=>'bob','age'=>'20'));
```

Answer (score 0):

But there is no such built in function in yii , Here is the available builtin function

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail ,

You can use this custom function in your model

```
public function find_or_initialize_by($array){

$model = Person::model()->find('name=:name AND age=:age',array(':name'=>$array["name"],':age'=>$array["age"]));

if($model == null){ 
    $model = new Person;
}

$model->name = $array["name"];
$model->age = $array["age"];
$model->save();

}
```